# Why is __func__ lowercase while __FILE__ and __LINE__ are uppercase?

Tags: c++

The preprocessor macro `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are uppercase.
Is there a reasoning behind having `__func__` lowercase?

Comment: `__func__` isn't a macro?

Comment: Why does it matter?